# CefSharp Wpf Как проверить сайт полностью загрузился?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Тренируюсь с CefSharp и столкнулся с тем что не могу найти как сделать проверку на то загрузился ли сайт полностью. При клике на кнопку открывается сайт и после того как он полностью загрузился я хочу вывести сообщение. А получается сообщение появляется а сайт еще не открылся. Помогите пожалуйста решить эту проблему, в интернете искал но понятного решения так и не нашел.

Вот что сейчас имею.

```xml
<Window x:Class="CefSharpApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CefSharpApp"
        xmlns:cef="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="900">
    <Grid>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Click="Button_Click" Grid.Column="0" Content="google" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5, 5 ,5 ,0"/>
        <cef:ChromiumWebBrowser Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Browser_Test"  Address="" />
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
using CefSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace CefSharpApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Browser_Test.Address = "https://google.com";

            MessageBox.Show("Сайт полностью загружен");
        }
    }
}
```

Помогите написать правильно код. Чтобы сообщение появлялось только после того как сайт полностью загрузился и отобразился.

Comment: А нет такого понятия: полностью загрузился. Может быть множество событий на странице: прокрутил страницу - данные подгрузились, нажал на кнопку - данные подгрузились, шевельнул мышкой - ну вы поняли?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41985473/5045688

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov вопрос и оветы почитал. Но как написать код в моем проекте не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/41985473/5045688

> вопрос и ответы почитал. Но как написать код в моем проекте не знаю.

Обработчик события `Click` для кнопки можете же создать? Вот здесь то же самое.

```xml
<cef:ChromiumWebBrowser LoadingStateChanged="Browser_LoadingStateChanged" ... />
```

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Browser_Test.Address = "https://google.com";
    }

    private void Browser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!args.IsLoading)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Сайт полностью загружен");
        }
    }
}
```