# Как в CefSharp вызвать метод LoadingStateChanged для проверки загрузилась ли страница?

Tags: c#, cefsharp

Знаю что в CefSharp имеет событие LoadingStateChanged но как его вызывать не знаю.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Я хочу сделать эту проверку именно при клике на кнопку goGoogle_Click.

Причем в будущем будет несколько таких кнопок и в каждой хочу проверять загружена ли страница.

```
private void goGoogle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

     BrowserCEF.Address = "https://google.com";
     // И тут проверить загрузилась страница или нет
     MessageBox.Show("Страница загрузилась");


}
```

Когда то я уже задавал такой вопрос, но там речь шла просто о проверки код был такой.

```
private void Browser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (!args.IsLoading)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Сайт полностью загружен");
    }
}
```

Он конечно рабочей но как его выполнить в других функциях?

Пробую делать так, но содержимое переменной не меняется.

```
string loadStatus = "не загружена";

public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Browser_LoadingStateChanged(object sender, LoadingStateChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (!args.IsLoading)
    {
      string loadStatus = "загружена";
    }

}

private void goGoogle_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    BrowserCEF.Address = "https://google.com";
    MessageBox.Show(loadStatus);

}
```

Comment: Эм, я вам ведь дал [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1475829/220553), в котором подробно написано как и что делать. Пишете в XAML `LoadingStateChanged="Browser_LoadingStateChanged"`, готово, вот вам событие, которое вызывается браузером, ну а дальше делайте на его основе все, что хотите, например, устанавливайте переменной класса значение, а ее уже потом проверяйте в других методах. И да, в WPF не должно быть "несколько таких кнопок", ибо WPF это про привязки и XAML, научитесь ими пользоваться, ваш код должен быть в отдельном классе, а не в классе окна.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вот посмотрите как сделал - https://jsfiddle.net/t5m83hf9/1/ что не так?

Comment: Это вы должны сказать "что не так", а не я. И да, код в вопрос добавляйте, под ним есть кнопка "править", не забывайте, что SO это сайт, где сообщество собирает полезное не только авторам, но и будущим читателям, а ссылки, они протухают, да и вообще у меня лично эта ссылка без VPN не открывается...

Comment: `но содержимое переменной не меняется.` - как вы это поняли? Через `MessageBox`, который вызывается сразу после указания адреса? Ну ведь вы сами начали с этого вопроса и поняли, что там не будет дожидаться загрузки страницы. Ну и `string loadStatus` два раза с указанием типа, надеюсь опечатка...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ событие Browser_LoadingStateChanged разве не вызывается после каждой загрузки страницы? Я думал оно вызывается каждый раз и в нем хотел менять значение переменной loadStatus а потом уже в тех местах где мне это нужно просто проверять что в ней.

Comment: Так и есть, но только сейчас ваш код как работает? Вы задали адрес, браузер начал думать, вы не дожидаясь его завершения выводите на экран сообщение, потом, когда браузер что-то там сделал, вы отловили его событие и поменяли "статус", но сообщение уже ведь было показано с изначальным статусом. Вообще, советую забыть про `MessageBox`, у вас ведь стоит IDE, которая имеет уйму механизмом отладки, одним из которых является точка остановки, поставьте ее (слева от нужной строки, где цифры, наведите туда мышь и кликните, появится красная точка), ну и дальше, когда код дойдет до туда, вы увидите все.